# Each time getting SocketTimeOut Exception while uploading an image

Tags: android, android-layout, image-upload, multipartentity, socket-timeout-exception

I have added a screen in my app in which a user uploads image from gallery or camera with some details  and send it to server but the problem is this when I click on submit button each time I got "SocketTimeOutException" but mail sent to server. Please help.

I was able to upload form earlier but not now. What is the problem I am not able to get.

Code:

```
 private void execMultipartPost() throws Exception {

    RequestBody requestBody;






    if (filePath != null) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        String contentType = file.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
        fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file);
        filename = "file_" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;


        Log.d("TAG", "execMultipartPost: " + filePath);


        requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("destination_type", selectedDescription)
                .addFormDataPart("admin_id", admin_id)
                .addFormDataPart("date", txtDate)
                .addFormDataPart("time", txtTime)
                .addFormDataPart("description", txtDescription)
                .addFormDataPart("image", filename + ".jpg", fileBody)
                .addFormDataPart("user_id", user_id)
                .addFormDataPart("api_token", api_token)

                .build();

    } else {


        requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("destination_type", selectedDescription)
                .addFormDataPart("admin_id", admin_id)
                .addFormDataPart("date", selectdate.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("time", selecttimehr.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("description", description.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("image", "null")
                .addFormDataPart("user_id", user_id)
                .addFormDataPart("api_token", api_token)

                .build();


    }

    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(Constansts.LETS_MELDEN)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();


    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();


    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.txt_error_occured), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                        String content = responseBody.string();
                        Log.e("TAG", "pic upload " + content);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);

                        if (jsonObject.has("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mail sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        description.setText(" ");
                        txt_picture_preview.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                        selecttypedec.setSelection(0);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();


                        //   Log.d("TAG", "response of image: " + response.body().string());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try to print your contentType and check if it is valid file type

Comment: getting file as "/storage/emulated/0/1524733769521.jpg"

Comment: and what is the value in contentType variable?

Comment: image/jpeg is the content type. I am able to get the form on email but in app getting some error occured

Comment: `I am able to get the form on email` ??? What do you mean by that?

Comment: `but in app getting some error occured`. Which exactly?

Comment: `uploads image from gallery or camera or send it to server` ?? What is the difference between uploading and sending to a server?

Comment: the above code is for a form. I am sending form using this code but the problem is this I got "some error occurred" but submitting the form and user get mail which contains all details of form @greenapps

Comment: What do you consider to be a form? How does one add a form to an app? No idea what you use or what you or the user is doing.

Comment: Don't consider it as a form. I have developer its UI as form. My question is when I hit api I got error but mail sent with all data to server

Comment: `I have developer its UI as form. ` ??? Sorry.. I have no idea what you are doing. Cant you start at the begin please.

Comment: Please check edit @greenapps

Comment: `have added a screen in my app` You told nothing! What is a screen? Come to the point!